# Bounded sequence in $L^1(\omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

**Edit:** With apologies for totally rewriting the question:

Suppose $f_n$ is a bounded sequence in $L^1(\omega)$, where $\omega$
is an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$. Need $(f_n)$ have an almost-everywhere-convergent subsequence?

(Of course if $L^1$ were reflexive we could start by applying Banach-Alaoglu to get a weak-* convergent subsequence. But it's not so we can't.)

---

Let $\omega$ be an open of $R^n$ and let $f_n$ be a bounded sequence in $L^1(\omega)$, As $L^1(\omega)$ is not refexive we can not ecxtract a convergente seubsequence, how can I deal with that. Thanks.

Comment: "how can I deal with that" is pretty vague. What are you trying to do?

Comment: is $f_n$ converge almosr everywhere to a limite $f$ ?

Comment: Please do not delete question once you got an answer. better improve the question via an [edit]

Comment: My apologies, I'm not so good in english, I couldn't express what was in my head. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

No. Counterexample in $L^1([0,1])$: Consider the Rademacher functions:

$$r_n=\sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1}(-1)^j\chi_{I_{n,j}},$$where $$I_{n,j}=[j2^{-n},(j+1)2^{-n}).$$If $r_{n_j}\to f$ almost everywhere then dominated convergence implies that $||r_{n_j}-f||_1\to0$, which is impossible since $$||r_n-r_m||_1=1\quad(n\ne m).$$

(In fact with a little more work one can show that any subsequence is almost everywhere divergent. The little more work is in showing that
$$\lim_{n,m\to\infty, n\ne m}\int_E|r_n-r_m|=|E|,$$where $|E|$ is the measure of $E$. **Edit:** Just realized this is much more obvious than I thought. Note that $|r_n-r_m|=\frac12(r_n-r_m)^2=1-r_nr_m$ and recall that finite products of Rademacher functions are orthogonal (these are the *Walsh functions*.))

**Note:** In fact we do have $r_n\to0$ weakly in $L^1$. So it seems that it wouldn't help much if $L^1$ *were* reflexive; convergence in the typical weak or weak-* topology evidently has very little to do with convergence almost everywhere.

Comment: Someone explain to me why someone would downvote _that_...

Comment: Because you answered an unclear question, in all likelihood. As you made at least clear what you are answering it's not that bad in my opinion. But still it is not universally appreciated, whence the dv, I assume.

Comment: @quid Oh - had no idea that answering a bad question was punishable. Heh, didn't say a word until he clarified in that comment. Thx.

Comment: Yes, that was a good thing to do. If OP does not get around to doing it you could consider cleaning up the question yourself a bit.

Comment: @quid Fine. The whole thing is now just lovely. Long ago there was this guy who used to really piss me off by rewriting my questions. If  I get in trouble for this I'm gonna blame you...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I will give you +1. According to the correct opinion the question is bad, the answer does not have to be bad! This would be a direct math mistake.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich no problem, I'll take the blame. :-) Thanks for your efforts.